# ¿Como actualizar un limite de registros en sql oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

espero y me puedan ayudar por favor, lo que pasa es que estoy creando una sentencia `update` pero quiero limitarle el numero de registros que deseo que se actualicen, es decir, realicé un count de todos los registros y me da un total de `44916` registros realizando esta consulta

```
SELECT REGION, COUNT(*) FROM COMPLEMENTO_PAGO_FACT WHERE TO_CHAR(FECHA_CREACION, 'DD/MM/YY') = '29/06/22' AND IND_GEN_CP ='N'and id_comp_pago_fact >40979581 and REGION ='R02'
GROUP BY REGION 
order by REGION asc;
```

Basandonos en la cantidad de registros que son 44916, de estos para actualizar como se podría realizar, actualmente tengo esto esta sentencia, pero estoy atorado en ponerle un limite, por ejemplo la mitad de registros antes mencionado, la sentencia sería la siguiente:

```
UPDATE COMPLEMENTO_PAGO_FACT
SET ind_procesado = REPLACE(ind_procesado, 0, 5)
WHERE ind_procesado =0
AND TO_CHAR(FECHA_CREACION, 'DD/MM/YY') = '28/06/22' AND IND_PROCESADO =0 and id_comp_pago_fact >40979581 and region ='R02'
--Aquí es donde quiero ponerle algún limite,
```

intenté poner el `limit` pero vi que no funciona así, hay alguna manera de sustituir el limit para el update? Espero y me ayudar por favor, se los agradecería mucho, gracias

Comment: si.. la forma es poniendo en el where una clausula que limite eso, haciendo referencia a un campo.. no, no podes usar limit ni nada de eso, porque para eso deberias ordenar la consulta, y no podes ordenar un update... porque querrias limitar un update?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que al ser muchisimos registros el sistema no tiene el soporte necesario para terminar de actualizar, por lo que se tendría que hacer un update temporal para que el sistema no los tomé (los actualizados) y solo tome la otra y no se sature

Comment: Pasa que el `LIMIT` no es un estándar en SQL, cambia dependiendo del DBMS, tienes que buscar para Oracle y yo que sepa el `ROWNUM` te puede ser de utilidad.

Comment: usa otro campo como filtro... no uses un limit (de ningun tipo).. usa la fecha o un id u otra cosa...

Comment: @gbianchi hola amigo, lo que pasa es son milies y miles de registros, por que si sería complicado seleccionar por ejemplo el campo id_comp_pago_fact, acabo de terminar la sentencia, igual si se podría quedar o se le puede mejorar mas, si funcionó pero está demas alguna mejora XD voy a responder mi pregunta con la sentencia que hice

Comment: No está demas alguna manita de gato*XD

Answer (score 0):

hice esta sentencia:

```
UPDATE COMPLEMENTO_PAGO_FACT
SET ind_procesado = REPLACE(ind_procesado, 0, 5)
WHERE ind_procesado =0
AND TO_CHAR(FECHA_CREACION, 'DD/MM/YY') = '04/07/22' AND IND_PROCESADO =0 and id_comp_pago_fact >4454881 and region ='R09'
 and rownum<=1;
```

Y si funcionó, para este ejemplo solo lo limité a 1 y si funcionó, igual si tuvieran alguna mejora con mucho gusto será bien recibida, saludos.

Comment: sin un order by, la fila que actualizas es totalmente aleatoria